# How to remove entry of ubuntu 12.04 from Windows bootloader while used (wubi installation)?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, 12.10, wubi

A few months I decided to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my PC alongside with my Windows 7 partition. In order to do that and avoid any mistake, I followed the steps of [this](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/2/) tutorial.

Everything was going well until I decided to update to the 12.10 release. I don't know what happened, but after I updated my Ubuntu, it stopped working, it didn't even launched, when I turned on my PC and choose to run "Ubuntu 12.04" on the Grub Screen, a weird messaged appeared.

Well, so I decided to install the Ubuntu 12.10 and forget about the 12.04 partition, no problem. 
I erased the partitions used for the Ubuntu 12.04 with EaseUS partition Manager.

However, when I start my PC, there is still the option of "Ubuntu 12.04" to chose, **is that bad?**

And what about now, can I use the [Windows Installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows) of Ubuntu to install the Ubuntu 12.10 ? What should I do to have Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows 7 in dual boot again?

Answer (score 1):

Put the Windows Vista or Windows 7 installation disc in the disc drive, and then start the computer.

Press a key when you are prompted.

Select a language, a time, a currency, a keyboard or an input method, and then click Next.

Click Repair your computer.

Click the operating system that you want to repair, and then click Next.

In the System Recovery Options dialog box, click Command Prompt.

Type following commands in cmd

```
bcdedit /export C:\BCD_Backup
c:
cd boot
attrib bcd -s -h -r
ren bcd bcd.old
bootrec /RebuildBcd
```

This will remove your old Ubuntu 12.04 entry.
After that you will able to boot Windows. Make fresh Installation of Ubuntu 12.10.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.

And about what you said about using Wubi, is Wubi any less eficient than the regular way of installing Ubuntu? Why?

Comment: It is just for trying Ubunutu Not permanant way to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Sure?
I understood things in a diferent way in this link http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows 
The last image is a picture from a boot screen, so I tought that it was a way of permanant istall of Ubuntu. Am I wrong?

Comment: No , It's wubi installation.

Comment: I cannot cd into boot because there apparently is no such directory. What to do now?

Answer (score 0):

Step:

1. Make a recovery disc for your Windows OS and this should save all the files you have when you create the recovery disc for Windows. follw this link for info on making a recovery disc http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows7/create-a-system-repair-disc
2. After the disc is created and fininshed leave the recovery disc in the cd-rom/dvd-rom drive
3. With the recovery disc inserted into the cd-rom/dvd-rom drive and restart your computer
4. Click/choose Repair your computer  when prompted.
5. Click the operating system that you want to repair, and then click Next.
6. In the System Recovery Options dialog box, click/choose Command Prompt.
7. Type following commands in cmd lines in the Command Prompt

bcdedit /export C:\BCD_Backup

c:

cd boot

attrib bcd -s -h -r

ren bcd bcd.old

bootrec /RebuildBcd

8 - This will remove your Ubuntu OS and Your Windows OS.

9 - restart your computer

10 - Upon start up enter into the computers BIOS by pressing whichever F# key is needed for you computer (the F# key will be displayed on the main screen when the computer starts up)

11 - In the BIOS screen arrow key over the the tab/section named BOOT, move the cd-rom/dvd-rom to the top of the list and then save all changes when prompted upon exiting the BIOS

12 - With the Windows Recovery disc in the cd-rom/dvd-rom drive restart your computer and follow the recovery prompts for Windows OS Recovery, after its finished you should only have Windows OS on your computer along with all your files

13 - After you have successfully recovered/restored you Windows OS your done, ENJOY!!!